# Не получается сравнить 2 объекта в Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я создаю команду "`команда @пользователь`" для ВК Бота на Python.

Написал код, чтобы Бот получил список всех пользователей беседы, а потом искал совпадающий `id`, указанный в сообщении.

Если `id` не совпадает, то он выдаёт сообщение об ошибке.

Иначе, начинает работать команда.

Часть кода:

```
members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(chat_id)
for i in members['profiles']:
    if screen_name_user2 == i['screen_name']:
        isIn = True
        break
    else:
        isIn = False
```

Проблема в том, что после выполнения цикла, в консоли просто выводится "`screen_name`", хоть я до этого указал, чтобы в консоль вывелись переменные `с сообщением, members, i`, и всё нормально.

Также после `for` остальной код не выполняется.

Comment: Проблема в том, что что-то не так выводится в консоль, а кусок кода, где ничего в консоль не отправляется. Лично я не представляю как понять по какой причине в консоль выводится одно сообщение, вместо другого, когда этого кода нет передо мной.

Comment: А точно у всех `members` есть поле `screen_name`? Не может у кого-то не быть такого поля? И сам `members` всегда ли не `None`?

Comment: @CrazyElf, кстати, да. У одного пользователя не было данного поля. Почему так?

Comment: Не знаю почему так, но эту ситуацию нужно предусмотреть и обработать. Либо проверкой наличия ключа в словаре, либо через get значение брать, либо исключение ловить.

Comment: Попробую что-нибудь. Спасибо